# Upgraded to MAMP PRO 3.2.0 for Windows Causing #1045 - Access denied Error

Tags: mysql, permissions, phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

Tried searching for this issue but doesn't seem to be anything specific to windows operating system.

I have just installed MAMP PRO 3.2 to demo before purchase. MAMP has been running fine for over a couple of years now running on windows 8.1.

However after installing MAMP PRO I can not see my dev sites and I can not access phpMyAdmin via the MAMP url. It throws an error:

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I know MAMP and MAMP PRO look at different locations for the db files so I have copied the **mysql folder** to the MAMP PRO db location. No passwords have been changed.

Anyone come across this issue and have a fix?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Copying the mysql folder alone might not be sufficient; in the datadir exist many files such as ibdata1 and so on which contain data from InnoDB table types. I would completely stop both MySQL instances, back up the MAMP PRO datadir, then completely replace it with the MAMP datadir. Then start only the MAMP PRO MySQL server; you don't want to accidentally have two MYSQL server instances running and competing for the same socket or port (or, much worse, using the same datadir).